# Não repetir numero de protocolo javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria que não repetisse os valores, e no click mostrar o código já sem repetição

```js
var vetor = [];
var auxiliaProtocolo = document.querySelector(".type");
var limiteMaximo = CheckMaxProtocol();
var botao = document.querySelector(".botao");

botao.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var verificadorVetorCheio = verificaTotalVetor(vetor);
  if (verificadorVetorCheio == true) {
    return;
  }

  var resultado = geraProtocolo();
  vetor.push(resultado);

  for (var i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < vetor.length; j++) {
      if (vetor[i] == vetor[j]) {
        vetor.pop(vetor[j]);
        var result = geraProtocolo();
        if (vetor[i] != result) {
          vetor.push(result);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

var botao2 = document.querySelector(".botao2");
botao2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (vetor.length > 0) {
    var novoProtoco = document.createElement("p");
    auxiliaProtocolo.appendChild(novoProtoco);
    novoProtoco.innerHTML = "Protocolo: " + vetor;
  }
});
```

Comment: Podes juntar o HTML e explicar o que deve acontecer para reproduzir o problema?

Comment: Um numero que não se repete é um auto_increment ou um algoritmo de aleatoriedade bastante complexo(que seria no seu caso com o js).